# How to get insertId for MySQL using Mysql2 in Node with async and pool?

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, connection-pooling, mysql2

I am trying to use async await with mysql2 and pooling but I think I doing things wrong. Below is my code (as I said, I am not really sure if I am doing things right here).

```
    const pool = mysql.createPool({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      password: '',
      waitForConnections: true,
      connectionLimit: 10,
      queueLimit: 0
    });
    
    const promisePool = pool.promise();   // Get a Promise wrapped instance of that pool   
    

app.post('/api/register', (req, res) => {

    async function queryDB() {
    
        try {
          const addUser = await promisePool.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (company, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)",
            ['Ikea', 'Ikea@ikea.com', '123'],
          )
          const addAnother = await promisePool.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (company, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)",
            ['Google', 'Google@google.com', '123']
          )
    
          console.log(addUser)
          res.status(200).json('Users saved')
          
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
          res.status(409).json('User already exist')
        };
      }
    
      queryDB();
})
```

The idea is that "addUser" should be saved, and if it is not unique, an error will occur (because the SQL database email column is set to unique) and then addAnother won't start inserting.

What I can't understand is how to get the insertId from the addUser insert? I will need it for the second insert. If I console.log addUser I can see an object like this:

```
ResultSetHeader {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 72,
  info: '',
  serverStatus: 2,
  warn
```

So insertId is sent back to me, but I can't seem to reach it. If I try to grab it it says cant read property of undefined. I am feeling that I am doing this all wrong, so how should I do it instead to get the insertID?

Comment: you only copy/pasted **part of the object**.  it's an array, and you have to take index 0.

Comment: Use a question-marked query, I think it's necessary to protect yourself from sql injection, I suggest you do your research.

Comment: hi, could you elaborate your answer? How would it be written instead?

Comment: I think this is done automatically by using "execute" instead of "query". From the documentation: "MySQL provides execute helper which will prepare and query the statement. Execute will internally call prepare and query": https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the result was in an array. I solved it with: `addUser[0].insertId`. I never got LAST_INSERT_ID() to work though.

Answer (score 5):

If you insert multiple rows into the same table, and the table has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key style column, the server assigns the values for you. You don't need to know the `insertId` of the first row you insert to get the second row inserted correctly.

The `insertId` value you need is in `addUser.insertId`.

```
          const addUser = await promisePool.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (company, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)",
            ['Ikea', 'Ikea@ikea.com', '123'],
          )
          const theInsertIdForAddUser = addUser.insertId
```

But notice that it also can be retrieved directly in the next MySQL statement via the SQL [LAST_INSERT_ID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html). That lets you do an operation like this.

```
   INSERT INTO users_properties 
           (key, value, userId)
    VALUES ('tel','555-1212',LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

You don't have to send the value back.

Comment: Hi, Sorry but both LAST_INSERT_ID() and addUser.insertId returns undefined. Any idea why this may be? The id is set as auto increment and is also the only PK.

Comment: note that you ***MUST*** fully understand transactions and atomicity in databases before doing multiple commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
insertId: 72
```

You have it in you response.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say, the reason why you couldnt get LAST_INSERT_ID() to work is because you are running your query directly from the connection pool.

So the pool will allocate one of it's connections to run your INSERT statement, but then it will allocate *another* connection to run your LAST_INSERT_ID() query. The second connection can't see the first connection's last inserted id.

Connection pools are great for performance and for making sure you never go over your hosting provider's max db connections limit...

So the solution for those times when you do need LAST_INSERT_ID(), or any time you need to run dependant statements one after the other, all on the same connection, is to use the [pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release() code flow](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).